# Firebase passwordless login email link expiration time is too short

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a use case where I need to send an email with Firebase passwordless login link. The admin of the website can invite another user to join a website by sending an email. And after the new user clicks on the link he has to be logged in in order to create a password.

The problem is that this link expires in a few hours. I need the link to be valid for at least a few days. There's no information about the email link expiration in Firebase documentation. However, I've found other discussions in forums stating that it's not possible to change the expiration time of email links in Firebase.

Has anyone know better options than using passwordless user login email link in a case sunch as mine where I have to send an email for a user to create a password?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to extend the expiration time of the one-time password in the
password link authentication emails. That's because they are meant to be used by the user themselves to sign into the application, and not in the way that you are using them.

To implement your scenario, I'd send a regular email to the user inviting them. Then the user can request to receive an email to sign in, and you won't have problems with the expiration.